# Install APK to Android device with Kivy

Tags: python, android, installation, kivy, apk

So I'm a Kivy user and I just learned how to request permissions from my apps. I've now made apps with the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `SEND_SMS`, `WAKE_LOCK`, and `VIBRATE` permissions. Now I want to be able to install APK files to the Android device with the `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission. But I don't know how to install the APK to the Android device. Does anyone know how I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From kivy.org:
Release on the market¶
If you have built your own APK with Buildozer or with python-for-android, you can create a release version that may be released on the Play store or other Android markets.

To do this, you must run Buildozer with the release parameter (e.g. buildozer android release), or if using python-for-android use the --release option to build.py. This creates a release APK in the bin directory, which you must properly sign and zipalign. The procedure for doing this is described in the Android documentation at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually - all the necessary tools come with the Android SDK.

https://gist.github.com/dustinfarris/8876216

Comment: Yes, I know how to convert my project into an APK. But what if I want to create an app like Google Play Store? How do I make my app install other APK files to the Android device?

Comment: you may take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/dustinfarris/8876216

Comment: It looks like it might be helpful, but what's `jnius`? What's `autoclass`?

Comment: its a python library for accessing Java classes. you can look at the docs if you want [jnius docs](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). [this](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius) is helpful too.

Comment: I don't know how to use `pyjnius` though. So can you please share just the code that it would take to open an application? Then, I'll try to understand that code.